Elastic cloud not raising CPU and Memory alert
I have created a CPU usage inventory rule alert with the following parameters:

Checks every: 1 minute.
Notify: Every time the rule is active. Condition: For Hosts when CPU
usage is above 1% for the last 1 minute.

and the memory inventory alert with following condition:

Checks every: 1 minute. Notify: Every time the rule is active.

Condition: For Hosts when Memory usage is above 1% for the last 1
minute.


I have created these in 'monitoring deployment'. My logs and metrics from deployment A are being sent to 'monitoring deployment' so these alerts should effectively be monitoring deployment A.
Also my usage for Deployment A is as follows:


Due to some reason I am not receiving notification for these 2 alerts. I tried to change the alerts to metrics alerts and use condition.

When Average of system.cpu.user.pct is above 1%.
When average of system.memory.actual.used.pct is above 1%.

Is this a data monitoring issue or rule creation issue and how can I correct it?
